# Livefyre and Wordpress - display total number of comment likes for a post

Tags: javascript, wordpress, livefyre

Using the [Livefyre](http://wordpress.org/plugins/livefyre-comments/) plugin for WP, I'm trying to display a total number of comment "likes" for each blog post. I can't figure out how to access the total number of Livefyre comment "likes" for a given post, or in Livefyre terms, a given collection.

The closest thing I can find is the ["Most liked" API](https://github.com/Livefyre/livefyre-docs/wiki/Most-Liked-API), but even if I add all the "likes" returned, I'll still only have the total number of the 25 most-liked pieces of content. This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688074/how-to-find-users-who-like-a-certain-comment-in-livefyre) is also somewhat related, but it seems to have more to do with the user data than the total collection data.

I'm new to Livefyre so maybe this is simpler than I'm making it out to be. I did look through the Livefyre documentation though and couldn't find any way to get a JSON object with the total likes for a collection.

Anyone know if this information is available through one of the Livefyre APIs, or otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you need the JS API https://github.com/Livefyre/livefyre-docs/wiki/Comment-Counts or a backend solution https://github.com/Livefyre/livefyre-docs/wiki/Content-Count-API

Answered already at [How to get comment count on livefyre?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727481/how-to-get-comment-count-on-livefyre/14732402#14732402)